Change default account for Azure Portal
Whenever I access Azure Portal in a new tab, it defaults to my primary account as the logged-in one (shown at the top right of the screen). It shows that my secondary account is available to quickly access (logged-in, but not in use). However, I usually use my secondary account for most of my work in Azure Portal, so I have to manually switch accounts for every tab.
How do I make Azure Portal default to use my secondary account by default whenever I open a new tab? The secondary account is already logged-in, so I figure this should be possible.
My primary account is the same as the one logged into my PC and to Edge, the browser I use for work.
My secondary account is a more secure account but it's always available and doesn't require MFA or other credential input to switch to.
Account popup showing secondary account available but not active

Can you better define what separates your primary and secondary accounts? Do you mean the account signed in to the computer perhaps? Which browser? Are you using SSO? If so, for which account?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Thanks, I've added the relevant details. They're both accessible from Edge without any additional credentials provided. Does the screenshot help as well? It's hard to put into words.

When you open a new tab are you working in a new blade? I find auth decisions don't go across blades in Azure. Also, I'd consider using Firefox or another alternate browser and only signing into it with your "secondary" account as the best way to accomplish this. If you really must use Edge, use one of the Beta or Canary Edge builds, which can run alongside regular Edge without issues.

simplest answer is to use an incognito/Private window or a different browser for each account.  Browsers dont deal well when there are auth/session for more than one identity for a single domain at the same time. I don't think that Azure is picking one, but that your browser is sending the cookies for the primary user.

Thanks music2myear and Frank, both of those look like good answers. Feel free to create them as answers and I'll accept them, just wanted to see if there was a simpler approach :)

Turns out there is an Edge setting for this :) However, if your browser is managed by your organization, you can install a second browser like Edge Beta, sign into the second browser with only your second account, and use SSO to sign in with your secondary account.
After enabling "Automatically sign in to sites with your current work or school account?", it no longer shows the "choose your account" sign in page when duplicating or opening Azure portal tabs :D
automatically sign in to sites with your current work or school account
profile preferences for sites
Source: Automatically choose Microsoft account based on Edge profile when signing in - Super User
